# How to import file to Tkinter and run script?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter

I have a python script that I want to add to a user interface to make it better for other people with absolutely no programming knowledge to use it. The python script imports an excel file from user input function, does some formatting, and returns an excel file with xlsx write, for example:

```
## user input excel file
file = input("Name of the file:")
df = pd.read_excel(file)

## some type of function like this
df.loc[df["Amount"] < 0 ,'Credit'] = df['Amount']
df.loc[df["Amount"] > 0 ,'Debit'] = df['Amount']

## writing resulting data frame to excel, also with user input
import xlsxwriter

file_name = input("Name of the file with xlsx extension:")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='yyyymmdd',
                        date_format='yyyymmdd')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = ('Sheet1'))


workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_column('B:AV', 40)
writer.save()
```

I am trying to adapt the code to Tkinter:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import sys
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

top=tkinter.Tk()

def Translation():
    os.system('python translation-app.ipynb')

B = tkinter.Button(top,text="FEC File For France",command= Translation)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

but the button does not do anything when it gets clicked (translation-app.ipynb is the jupyter script I want to use)

I am a complete beginner at Tkinter, so any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want the gui to open the notebook? Or just to run the code contained in the notebook?

Comment: 1st you need to remove `import tkinter`. You are importing tkinter twice. 2nd I would change `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter as tk` then anywhere you need to reference tkinter just use the `tk.` prefix. IE `root = tk.Tk()`. That all said what does `'python translation-app.ipynb'` refer to. Is this a python script? Is that the python code you have above your tkinter GUI code? If so you will have to move it into your GUI code and change `imput()` to `tk.Entry()` and get that info from the user in the GUI directly. Let me know if the top code is the `ipynb` file and i I will edit it.

Comment: @CHaworth run the code contained in the notebook (:

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks so much! the translation-app.ipynb is the jupyter notebook that contains the code I wrote for the excel file (for example the lines of code I wrote in the post). I don't need to open the notebook directly if that is complicated, I can just copy and paste the code..but I am not sure where to do it inside the GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple version of what you are looking for. Instead of using `input()` you use an entry field to get the data from the user.

Take a look at the below and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import xlsxwriter



root = tk.Tk()

def Translation():
    file = input("Name of the file:")
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    ## user input excel file
    ## some type of function like this
    df.loc[df["Amount"] < 0, 'Credit'] = df['Amount']
    df.loc[df["Amount"] > 0, 'Debit'] = df['Amount']
    ## writing resulting data frame to excel, also with user input
    file_name = entry2.get()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format='yyyymmdd', date_format='yyyymmdd')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=('Sheet1'))
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    worksheet.set_column('B:AV', 40)
    writer.save()

tk.Label(root, text="Name of the file:").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Name of the file with xlsx extension:").grid(row=1, column=0)
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(root, text="FEC File For France", command=Translation).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really can't thank you enough for your help (: